# Power Pivot Removing External Link(from MS Access)

Tags: powerpivot

I have Power Pivot with data sourced from MS Access Table. The Data in MS Access changes every day. But we want the Power Pivot model data to be static. i.e. it must not get updated when refreshed.

The Excel file is saved for future reference as back up & every day new Excel file is created with fresh data.

Want to Remove Link because, if i press refresh in back up file i don't want to fetch the latest data in that file.

I want the data in the Model without connection to  MS Access. (Same as remove external link in Excel sheet & keeping the data.)

earlier i tried to find if there is some functionality similar to remove links, but could not find.

Comment: So far as I know there's no way to do what you want. On the other hand, you could simply rename the Access file, then Power Pivot refresh would fail. In general, using Power Pivot as a backup strategy is probably not the best.

Comment: Thanks for feedback:

Comment: 1) i am using for Power Pivot for Dashboards & sharing the huge data with other team member. 2) Some times have to go to back dated file & do ahoc working. During this i face challenges if need to add some more  columns or link, as it gets refreshed & pull fresh data in earlier saved file.